# What PPL routes are available with gliding experience?

Tags: easa-regulations, caa-uk-regulations, sailplane, lapl, tmg

I'm an early solo glider pilot, with the long term goal of also obtaining a PPL (not a LAPL(A)).  I am planning to do this after I have obtained at least my bronze badge, which I aspire to within the next twelve months.

Originally I thought that the only route open to me was to do the full PPL.  My understanding was that I can get a credit of 10% of P1 hours on a glider deducted from the requirements (max 10 hrs), however the CAA website refers to holders of "a pilot’s licence for another type of aircraft, except balloons".  I'm not sure if that applies to a bronze holder or if I would need to obtain a LAPL(S) or SPL for them to count (for which I would presumably need a bronze XC endorsement to make the required XC flight).

If I obtain a LAPL(S), then according to the CAA I can add a TMG rating (6+ hrs) and then, after hours building (24hrs) do a conversion course (15+ hrs) to the full PPL(A).  It's not clear if this route is available if I obtained an SPL, although for a fee I believe you can swap licences.

Can P1 hours as a glider pilot count towards a PPL(A) without obtaining a LAPL(S)/SPL?

Is the LAPL(S) -> TMG -> PPL route viable? Would I need to go to an "ATO" for TMG training or can my local gliding club do this?

Aside from just doing a PPL from scratch, are there any other viable routes that I've missed (e.g. via a LAPL(A) on a TMG somehow)?

Comment: if you can't get an answer here, you might try rec.aviation.soaring, where lots of UK glider pilots hang out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a partial answer after more research and some help on [pprune](http://www.pprune.org/private-flying/577812-routes-ppl-gliding.html).

A Bronze + XC can be used to get a gliding licence, which under the transitional arrangements can be used to obtain a LAPL(S).

In theory the route from there to a LAPL(S)+TMG  and on to a LAPL(A) TMG is feasible, however the BGA is not an ATO yet and there are very few instructors or examiners around.  This route may be problematic at the moment, but should become easier as time goes on.  There's no reason not to claim the LAPL(A) on the way to a PPL(A) if taking this route.

An alternative route is via an NPPL under the transitional arrangements.  After gaining the gliding certificate, a minimum of 10 hours under instruction is needed until reaching the standard for an NPPL SMLG.  After short conversion training, this can then be converted to an NPPL SSEA.  After 6 hours PIC this lot in turn can be traded in for a LAPL(A) SEP+TMG.  Complicated, but overall less hours and my much can be done at a BGA club with a motorglider and instructor.

Regarding the straight PPL(A) route with credit, given the statement

> If you hold a pilot’s licence for another type of aircraft, except
>   balloons, you will be credited with 10% of your total flight time as
>   PIC up to a maximum of 10 hours

it would seem clear that at that some form of licence is needed, and given the gliding licence qualifies for a LAPL(S) anyway, which one is moot.